# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException happens intermittently

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver, serenity-bdd

I'm facing an intermittent problem with running Selenium web tests in Serenity BDD framework executed in an Azure pipeline against a web application.

SessionNotCreatedExceptionthat is thrown sometimes at the beginning of a test suite.

I run tests from Azure pipelines and locally, on my laptop and from time to time get this error.

It looks like chromedriver cannot get in touch with the browser.
Has anyone experienced something similar?

Here's the sequence of exceptions:

```
net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError:
WebDriver was unable to create a new instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
WebDriver reported the following message: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
[...]
Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
[...]
WebDriver reported the following message: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.

Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to bind the port.
```

The problem is not related to unavailability of Chrome browser or Chrome webdriver.

Next test cases are usually successful - the browser is started and the webdriver controls it.

Comment: this can happen when running multiple drivers/browsers... after a driver quits the browser will take a certain amount of time to cleanup.  One of the things it'll cleanup is this file that's dropped containing the SessionID of the launched browser.  It can help to include a wait period after a driver quits and before a new chromedriver is launched.   This error has many causes, though... it can also be caused by an orphaned chromedriver process (crashed or not quit properly)

Comment: No, it happens for a single browser (Chrome) with a single driver (chromedriver) and when it happens on a Microsoft-hosted Azure pipeline agent, it's always the first test that tries to open the browser. When this happens, usually next test case is able to successfully start the browser and the whole test suite continues.

So a sequence is as follows:

1. A pipeline agent is started (Windows vm).
2. Initial steps are performed (screen resolution set up etc.)
3. Maven comes into play (mvn test ...)
4. First test scenario calls Selenium's get method to open a url and it fails.